# Trying to commit to a proposal with a mail on a new TLD fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, email, validation

I've tried to commit to an Area51 proposal with an email like so `stackexchange@somedomain.ninja`, which is a valid email on a domain I own (that's not the real email, obviously).

However, Area51 rejected my commitment with "That's not a valid email".

Comment: Ninjas are supposed to keep enemies away, not commit to proposals.

Comment: If you were actually a ninja you'd be able to get around that check.

Comment: @Won't I never said that I didn't :)

Comment: @Undo it was a proposal for a QA site on keeping enemies away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the Area 51 email validation procedures to be inline with those on the Q&A sites.

You should be able to ninja away, your sageness.

Comment: Thank you mortal, I'll give you a good dream in time.

Comment: Is there a white list of allowed domains??

Comment: @ShadowWizard - a simple regex. Just with expanded TLD matching.

Comment: Will `stackexchangerulz@somedomain.shadowwizard` work then? ;)

Comment: It may pass that specific test, but to register you will need a confirmation link sent to that email address... @sha